# Javascript Student - Returning an array via index # - Parameter question

Tags: javascript, arrays

[image]

Please see attached image for instructions.
I'm currently a student studying for web development, I've noticed parameters being called arguments when I was under the impression, you create the argument outside of the bracket. Is this true?

How do I got about selecting parameters for a function? For example, I cannot get a console.log when I add parameters into this function in the image.

I'm  also having trouble returning a specific "flavor of ice cream" with an index number. When, I attempt to do a console.log, it returns the flavor from the preset array above in the assignment.

Any tips? I need a better understanding of this going forward. Thank you for your help.

```
function getFlavorByIndex(){

    console.log(originalFlavors[2])

}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions

Comment: You are not supposed to have the hard coded number in the arguments. I think you are confusing the function call and the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are new to programming I'll try to simplify it as much as posible: first you define a function (give it a name, indicate the required parameters, and what it does to them):

```
function getFlavorByIndex(originalFlavors, anyIndex){

  console.log(originalFlavors[anyIndex])

}
```

Then you call/execute the funcion, with actual values:

```
 getFlavorByIndex(['Apple','Banana','Coconut', 'Donut'], 2);
//prints 'Coconut'
```

Answer (score 1):

From the **[MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Parameter)** (emphasis added):

> Note the difference between parameters and arguments:
>
> - Function parameters are the *names* listed in the function's definition.
> - Function arguments are the *real values* passed to the function.

So it looks like you need something like this:

```
function getFlavorByIndex(flavorsArray, index) {
    return flavoursArray[index];
}
```

Where `flavorsArray` and `index` are the two parameters.

If you wanted to test the `getFlavorByIndex` function you would call it using something like:

```
let originalFlavors = ["Apple", "Banana", "Carrot"];
console.log(getFlavorByIndex(originalFlavors, 1));
```

In the above call, which would output `"Banana"` to the console
`originalFlavors` and `1` are the arguments to the `getFlavorByIndex` function and result of that call is the argument to the [**console.log** method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log).

You might also want to read the MDN Web Docs for [**return**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return):

> The return statement ends function execution and specifies a value to
> be returned to the function caller.